# Can't use GeoMipMap in Panda3D

Tags: python, video, panda3d

I'm on to a very new 3D video Game project using Panda3D, and i try to understand the basics of terrain loading, that's why i tried the Panda3D tutorial ( https://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/Geometrical_MipMapping), telling to type this in Python :

```
terrain = GeoMipTerrain("mySimpleTerrain")
terrain.setHeightfield("yourHeightField.png")
#terrain.setBruteforce(True)
terrain.getRoot().reparentTo(render)
terrain.generate()
```

which i did, though i have a :

```
Name Error : Name " GeoMipTerrain " is not defined
```

It is said in the Panda3D manual that GeoMipMap is included in Panda3D since 1.5.1 so i should be juste fine, they just don't say if we must import a specific module or what. That's why i tried to look what module or thing was necessary to load before requesting such a command, but i found no result, that's why i require your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the class before you can use it in Python:

```
from panda3d.core import GeoMipTerrain
```

You can also choose to import everything under the `panda3d.core` namespace instead of importing classes individually:

```
from panda3d.core import *
```

It is also available under `pandac.PandaModules`, however, this is deprecated, and should not be used.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it will avoid much trouble :)

Answer (score 0):

It's ok i found how on someone's code, it's :

```
from pandac.PandaModules import GeoMipTerrain
```